# If all bits are 0, what is the value of IEEE floating point?

Tags: c, floating-point

If all bits are 0 (example I `memset` the floating point variable to all 0), what is the value of IEEE floating point used in gcc? It is guaranteed to be 0.0 ?

I guess for other floating point formats result may vary. But my question is specific to IEEE floating point used with gcc.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the implementation is IEEE 754 compliant there exist special cases for different bit-combinations, like documented [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).

For your case: When all bits (sign, exponent, mantissa) are zero the floating point value represents also zero, as defined by IEEE 754. More specifically, that value is a "positive zero", also written as +0.

Comment: The sign bit can be 0 or 1 for +0 or -0 respectively.