# How do I properly create a matrix in C with malloc?

Tags: c, matrix

So, I wrote this C function that receives an integer n and is supposed to create a matrix with n lines and n + 1 columns.

The problem that I'm facing right now is that all the values in the column n (last column) are not initialized as 0.0, unlike all the other seeds from the matrix.

Here is my code:

```
float** createMatrix(int n){
    float **matrix;
    int numLines = n;
    int numCol = n + 1;

    matrix = (float**) malloc(numLines*sizeof(float *));
    if(matrix == NULL) abort();

    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++){
        matrix[i] = (float*) malloc(numCol * sizeof(float));
        if (matrix[i] == NULL)
            abort();
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Would really appreciate some help. I've been stuck on this bug for a while now.

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't initialize the allocated memory — it contains indeterminate values.  You can probably use `calloc()` instead.  Or explicitly initialize the memory after allocating it.

Comment: It’s not “a bug” - malloc doesn’t claim to initialise the memory it allocates.

Comment: @Gonçalo Costa Why does the matrix have n + 1 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory returned from `malloc` is not initialized.  Each byte can contain any value.

You can instead use `calloc` which initializes all bytes to 0.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++){
    matrix[i] = calloc(numCol, sizeof(float));
    if (matrix[i] == NULL) abort();
}
```

Comment: This will _probably_ work, (if [IEEE 754](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8558852/2472827).) If you want to be sure, loop through and set then to zero manually.